# providing DNS client and Ping client

Tags: dns, network-programming, embedded-linux, icmp

I have a device firmware which runs on Ubuntu operating system. And the device has Ethernet connectivity and will connected on the network.

Now i need provide these two functionalities on the device

1. ICMP ping client - so that a device can ping the other devices on the network.
2. DNS client - for faster hostname to IP resolution instead of going to DNS server all the time.

I am trying to find how can i provide these features ? Do i need to implement these features or i can get some ready made source code or libraries which i can integrate with the existing code and get the features working.

Thanks in advance.

Sagar

Comment: For DNS what you want is a local *server*, or caching proxy. If you can resolve hostnames then you already have a client. There are a few light-weight solutions already. Might even be in the standard Ubuntu repository. As for "ping", there isn't a `ping` command in the default install? Have you tried looking for it in the Ubuntu repositories? Or do you mean you want "ping" as a *library* to be used by other applications without the need to execute an external command?

Comment: I need to provide these feature on some measurement device on which the operating system may not have these features implemented by default. so i would like to implement these on my own and cross compile to the device.